How to display Cell Borders with Cell Values after incorporating Image as Background in DGV?
After incorporating the Img Wanted to display Normal Gridlines or all the Cells in DGV with Borders and
respective Cell Values in Front of the Image
Below Tried almost everything but did not achieve anything.
I am not able to see the Each Cell All Borders of DGV3 as Background image already in corporated in DGV3 with below coding.
Your guidance will be appreciated

Private bgImage As Drawing.Image

Public Sub New()
     bgImage = Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\Images\VPBSSquare.Jpg") 
     ResizeImage(bgImage)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView3_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, 228, 228)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView3_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellPainting
'Option 1
        DataGridView3.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
'OPtion 2
Dim columnindex As Integer
        If e.RowIndex <> -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = columnIndex Then

            If (e.PaintParts And DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) <> DataGridViewPaintParts.None Then
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bgImage, e.CellBounds)
            End If

            If Not e.Handled Then
                e.Handled = True
                e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds)
            End If
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView3_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellFormatting
'Option 3
        e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        DataGridView3.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
        DataGridView3.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
        DataGridView3.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Raised
End Sub

Thanks SsD
I tried each and every Option as above. Did not achieve anything
Effort 2nd
I tried in the following manner by creating another project
What I realised is that SystemColors.ActiveCaption is perfect rectangular or Square scissor Cut piece of parent form
so Form is with precise neat shape of scissors/blade cut with respective location and Size
This was Like holding a tray of Glass(Form) with DGV values printed on glass and Image stuck on the glass near DGV values.
If you want see the above effect kindly see the below coding and implement yourself.
I slightly moved the location of DGV to see the overall effect and the overall effect is mentioned in regards to above glass tray.
What is required would like to send picturebox back of DGV with DGV values in front ?
So with SystemColors.ActiveCaption it is exact hollow cut
and with Colors.Transparent is White background so this is not transparent but a White Opaque patch.
Although I incorporated PictureBox1.BringToFront() and DataGridView1.SendToBack() nothing seems to work
Private bgImage As Drawing.Image

Private Sub DGVImage2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Call FormLayout()
End Sub

Private Sub FormLayout()

    Dim bgImageStr As string = "C:\Images\VPBSSquare.Jpg"

    Me.TransparencyKey = SystemColors.ActiveCaption
    PictureBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption

   PictureBox1.Location = New Point(286, 41)
   PictureBox1.Size = New Size(228, 228)
   PictureBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption
   PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(bgImageStr)
   PictureBox1.BringToFront()

   DataGridView1.Location = New Point(186, 41)
   DataGridView1.Size = New Size(228, 228)
   DataGridView1.SendToBack()

      For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Height = 76
        Next i

      For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width = 76
            DataGridView1.Columns(i).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 30, FontStyle.Bold)
            DataGridView1.Columns(i).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            ''DataGridView1.Columns(i).ReadOnly = True
        Next i
End Sub

Thanks SsD

I've explored and found that this cannot be worked out in either the ways
and thus resolved by NOT Implementing on any of the posts(edited..etc) that were posted by me.
Inconvenience Regretted.
Thanks SsD
